# Going through all values between all points of data in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series, visualization, data-processing

I have data. Let's say:

```
date,comments
19-Apr-2016,Today was great.
21-Apr-2016,Today was not so great.
1-May-2016,Interesting things happened!
```

(All dates are parsed as dates of course)

I want to go through every day from April 19th, 2016 to May 1st 2016 and make an element for every single *day*, and then inject relevant data where it exists. For example:

```
19-Apr-2016 - Today was great.
20-Apr-2016 - <No entry>
21-Apr-2016 - Today was not so great.
22-Apr-2016 - <No entry>
...
1-May-2016 - Interesting things happened!
```

This is the current code. It does the former and creates an element for every point of data:

```
preview.selectAll("svg")
    .append("g")
    .data(sums)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    // Drawing code etc. Setting height, class, color, w/e
```

How do I loop through all days regardless of whether there's data for them?

Comment: kinda need to show us more code, preferably your data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the pseudocode of how i'll approach this problem.

Imagine your sums object is an array which stores the data represented by you

`19-Apr-2016 - Today was great.
20-Apr-2016 - <No entry>
21-Apr-2016 - Today was not so great.
22-Apr-2016 - <No entry>
...
1-May-2016 - Interesting things happened!`

Now in my function where i draw i ll do like this

```
var start = new Date(2016, 3, 19);//19-Apr-2016
var end = new Date(2016, 4, 1);//1-May-2016
for (var d = start; d <= end; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
  //for each date append a group
  var grp = preview.selectAll("svg").append("g")
  var myData = //get the data from sums array for which the date is d(in iterator)
  if(myData){
    grp.append("rect").style("stroke", 1) ...
  }else {
   //date not in the sums array.
  }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

D3's built-in [`nest`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Arrays#nest) is probably the simplest way to do this.

Don't bind `sums` directly. Group the data first by date with `nest` and draw your chart based on that grouping.

Comment: Hey. I edited my question a bit. Maybe it makes more sense now.